# Geofield (geocode from another field) - database entry not created

Tags: 7

On a Drupal 7.63 site, I have a content type with a "Postal Address" field ([address module](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield), v7.x-1.3) (mandatory) and a "Geofield" field ([geofield module](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield), v7.x-2.4). The geofield field has no input interface: it uses the "Geocode from another field" widget and is configured to use the Postal Address field as a source. Its information is then used to render a small map using Google Map ("Geofield map").

My issue is that when creating new nodes, the geofield field remains empty and no map is rendered. And when updating the address on existing nodes, the map isn't updated (it still shows the old point).

I checked directly in the database (table `field_data_field_geofield`), and can confirm that the rows corresponding to the new nodes are *not* there. So it seems the data is never created in the table, but I don't know why.

I see no error message on the edit page of the nodes or in the recent log page (admin/reports/dblog).

The addresses used for those nodes are correctly formed and stored (I checked the `field_data_field_adresse` table); they are rather simple and can easily be found on Google Maps. (Example: Grand-Rue 5, 2900, Porrentruy, Switzerland)

I tried applying the patch provided in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield/issues/3030268), but it didn't solve my problem, even when creating new content (I have since rolled back this change). Maybe it's not the same problem.

**Update:** after more research, [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder/issues/3002517) seems to describe my problem. However:

- applying patch #29 doesn't solve the problem
- applying patch #41 doesn't solve the problem
- downgrading geocoder to v.1.3 doesn't solve the problem either.

Any suggestion on what is wrong would be greatly appreciated. What else should I check for?

(It's on a website that has used this system for several years and it's the first time I see this problem.)

(I created a [request support ticket](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield/issues/3032406) on the geofield page last week, but so far I haven't received any feedback.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the problem actually had two causes, which made it more difficult to solve than it should have been:

1. a bug in the geocoder codebase (solution: apply [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/geocoder/issues/3002517#comment-12937777))
2. the Google Maps API key used in the geocoder configuration was actually invalid for this type of operation, and so I had to generate another key specifically for geocoding operations. (I noticed the problem via a geocoder error saved in the recent log entries pages.)